# Check ps aux process

Tags: bash, shell

Doing `ps aux|grep paramount` when the program is running gives me:

```
david          80810  95.1  3.6  3113624 599036 s007  RN+   1:43PM   0:01.54 python ./parse_paramount.py
david          80812   0.0  0.0  2432768    600 s011  R+    1:43PM   0:00.00 grep paramount
```

Doing the same command when the program is not running gives me:

```
david          80809   0.0  0.0  2432768    588 s011  R+    1:43PM   0:00.00 grep  paramount
```

How would I write a bash script to return `true` if the program is running and `false` if it is not running?

Comment: Don't. Use `pgrep` instead.

Comment: ...though if your goal is to restart something when it's down, you shouldn't use pgrep either -- you should be using a process-supervision framework that takes advantage of the wait() call to get immediate notice without polling when its children exit. Many, many of these exist -- runit, daemontools, supervisor, upstart, systemd... even SysV init with an inittab in use with the restart flag.

Comment: Alternately, you can use a lock file with `flock` to get a better idea of whether something is running holding the lock -- the `ps aux` approach gives you all kinds of false positives, such as flagging `vim paramount.py` as if it were `paramount` itself, whereas tying state to a lockfile prevents name conflicts from being meaningful.

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several good suggestions in the comments for other approaches.  To answer your specific question, there is a trick to use:

```
ps aux|grep '[p]aramount'
```

`grep` supports regular expressions.  This works because the regex `[p]aramount` matches the string `paramount` but it does not match the string `[p]aramount`.

It is important to place `[p]aramount` in quotes, as shown above, so that `bash` does not mangle it before passing it to `grep`.